# Is there a better way to Save the files in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, win64

After making some changes in xyz.cpp file, when I am trying to save the whole project it asks to save files in the directory and ultimately it didn't get saved and an error message comes as

> The Process cannot access the files "c:\ml/src.cpp" because it is being used by another process.

Usually to get rid of this error I use to open another .cpp file and make some chnages in that and then try to save so that other unsaved files gets save with this and sometimes it didn't work well.
was wondering if there is any better way of handling it?

Comment: It seems strange that the pathname contains a mixture of `/` and ``\``. That could be a sign that you set the pathname wrongly. However, I am not sure if this can cause the posted error message.

Comment: Something is borked. Whether it's your project or your VS installation, I couldn't say.

Comment: Do you maybe have several instances of Visual Studio open on the same project? If you do, then it could be that they are disturbing each other.

Comment: It could be your antivirus if you are not trying to save when you are building.

Comment: Another vote for crappy antivirus from me

Comment: @AndreasWenzel it's just folder structure and suppose it is in the correct form.

Comment: Are you trying to save while compiling?

Comment: It is impossible that mixing slashes is in correct form when you're not escaping anything.

Comment: This is usually the result of a broken project file, presumably a .vcxproj. There aren't any easy solutions. The easiest would be to create a project fresh, and start adjusting it and copying all your source files over.

Comment: @MickaëlC.Guimarães No, it's like I have opened some projects and made some changes in some files and after changes when I am trying to save the file, I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

You should:

1. Download [ProcessExplorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)
2. Go to Find -> Find Handle or DLL
   [image]
3. Navigate to your file path:
   [image]

ProcessExplorer will tell you wich process are using/blocking your file.